# Как использовать addRegions

Tags: marionette.js, backbone.js

Привет.Есть специфическая библиотека marionette.js.
Какая цель создания регионов и как с ними работать?

Кто-то может подскажет документацию(не исход кода с коментариями)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

тут исчерпывающая информация по марионету
https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki